# can't run on snack expo android and ios but web is fine?

Tags: react-native, expo

this is my snack: https://snack.expo.io/@gpbaculio/petrified-peach

which runs perfectly fine on web, but on ios and android, i got this error:

[image]

and i also cannot import my git repo? https://github.com/gpbaculio/cs50project3

are there any sites like snack expo i can use? i just want to demo my react native project online